# Find the value of $\theta$

Tags: trigonometry

Given the equation $\frac{\pi\theta}{2(180)} - \frac{\sin\theta}{2} = 2.36$, I'm having difficulties finding the proper solution and using trigonometry in finding the value of $\theta$ I know that it can simply be solved by the use of calculator I think it's around $\theta=220$. But then again I would really love to know how it got that value, I've tried double angle formula and deriving it; however, it was not even close, help please. The formula was actually derived from a tank problem filled with water in an upright position then placed horizontally, the same value of $\theta$ pops out with the solution of $\pi-(\theta-\sin\theta \cos\theta)= \frac{3\pi}{4}$ Again, my only question is, how do you manually solve and find the value of $\theta$?

The actual problem is

An upright cylindrical tank contains water with a height of $3$m the tank is then laid horizontally and the water is cooled until it became a solid ice, if the tank diameter is $2$m and its length is $4$m find the height of in the horizontal tank. I was able to solve this and got 1.404m

however I would just like to understand how did my calculator got the value of $\theta$ from the equations above

One of my reference book in solid mensturation mentioned using trial and error or a new version of calculator. But how do I do the trial and error?

Comment: it's unusual to mix degrees and radians, which by including pi and the number 180 you appear to be doing. Fix this first and the problem will probably resolve more easily.

Comment: is this $$\frac{\pi \cdot \theta}{2\cdot 180^{\circ}}-\frac{\sin(\theta)}{2}=\frac{236}{100}$$?

Comment: then $\theta -\sin \theta=4.72$ I think we can use approximation method, and yes it's close to answer $220^0$

Comment: how did you use approximation and got that $\theta - sin\theta = 4.72$

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you want to solve $$\pi-(x-\sin(x) \cos(x))= \frac{3\pi}{4}$$ that is to say that you want the zero of $$f(x)=-x+\frac 12\sin (2x)  +\frac{\pi }{4}$$ which can only be solved using numerical methods.

However, we can approximate the solution. By inspection, the solution is between $\frac \pi 4$ ($f(\frac \pi 4)=\frac 12$ ) and $\frac \pi 2$ ($f(\frac \pi 2)=-\frac \pi 4$). So, let us consider the function around $x=\frac \pi 3$ and use Taylor series which give $$f(x)=\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}-\frac{\pi }{12}\right)-\frac{3}{2} \left(x-\frac{\pi
   }{3}\right)+O\left(\left(x-\frac{\pi }{3}\right)^2\right)$$ Using this term only, we get $$x=\frac{3 \sqrt{3}+5 \pi}{18} \approx 1.16134$$ which makes $\approx 209 \text{ degrees}$ while the exact solution would be $x\approx 1.15494$ making $\approx 208 \text{ degrees}$.

**Edit**

e could have a better approximation if, instead of Taylor series, we use the simplest Padé approximant built at $x=\frac{\pi }{3}$. This would give
$$f(x) \sim \frac{\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}-\frac{\pi }{12}\right)+\frac{1}{36} \left(\sqrt{3} \pi
   -63\right) \left(x-\frac{\pi }{3}\right) } {1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}(x-\frac{\pi }{3}) }$$ leading to 
$$x=\frac{\pi }{3}+\frac{3 \left(\pi -3 \sqrt{3}\right)}{\sqrt{3} \pi -63}\approx 1.15428$$

Answer (score 0):

> However I would just like to understand how did my calculator got the value of $\theta$ from the equations above.

The calculator uses numerical solution techniques. For example check [Newton's method](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NewtonsMethod.html).

Answer (score 0):

There is no general approach to find the roots of equations, and in the vast majority of the cases (such as yours), there exist no analytical formula. The root finders in use in calculators as well as PC software are based on so-called *numerical analysis* methods.

These work by evaluating the target function for different values of the independent variable, until a change of sign is found. Then the bracketing of the root is refined by computing the function at intermediate points. The computation stops when the bracketing is tight enough.

This is just the basic principle, and methods vary in their degree of sophistication. In particular, some rules are used to choose the intermediate points as a function of the previous ones and the function values they achieve, to predict better and better approximations of the roots. Among them, the methods of the secant, of the tangent (Newton's) or the inverse polynomial interpolation.